# Custom Post Type Won't Output Post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm creating a plugin and I have a custom post type set up that includes meta boxes, custom fields and custom taxonomies. All that is working fine and on my wordpress dashboard, the "add new post" is all there. However when I try to "save draft" or "publish" a post, it's not working. Error included below.

Here's the code for my CPT.

```
 // Register Custom Post Type
function post_type_book() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'All Books', 'book post type name', 'author_station' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Book', 'Singular book post type name', 'author_station' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Books', 'author_station' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'author_station' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'author_station' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'author_station' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'author_station' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'author_station' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Book', 'author_station' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'author_station' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Book', 'author_station' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Book', 'author_station' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'author_station' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Book', 'author_station' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'author_station' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'author_station' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not books found', 'author_station' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not books found in Trash', 'author_station' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Book Cover Image', 'author_station' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set Book Cover Image', 'author_station' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove Book Cover Image', 'author_station' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as Book Cover Image', 'author_station' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'author_station' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'author_station' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'author_station' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'author_station' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'author_station' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'book', 'author_station' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Custom Book Entry', 'author_station' ),
        'supports'              => array('title'),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'genres', 'series', 'keywords' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => false,
        'menu_position'         => 20,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'as_book' ),

    );
    register_post_type( 'as_book', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'post_type_book');







        function save_as_book( $post_id ) {
        // verify nonce
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['your_as_book_nonce'], basename(__FILE__) ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        // check autosave
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        // check permissions
        if ( 'page' === $_POST['as_book'] ) {
            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            } elseif ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        }

        $old = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'as_book', true );
        $new = $_POST['as_book'];

        if ( $new && $new !== $old ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'as_book', $new );
        } elseif ( '' === $new && $old ) {
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'as_book', $old );
        }
    } 
    add_action( 'save_post', 'save_as_book' );
```

This is the error that comes up when I try to 'save draft' or 'publish' a post.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object_id() on null in ..../wp-includes/query.php on line 60
```

Comment: This code seems to be working fine on my system. are you using any other custom post types?

Comment: No other CPTs. I just deactivated every plugin except the one I'm building, changed the theme from my custom to twenty-nineteen and even reset my permalinks. Still giving me the same error.

Comment: I tried getting rid of my custom taxonomies - didn't help.
I tried getting rid of my actual custom fields/meta-boxes which also didn't help.
That's all that's part of my plugin, the CPT, meta boxes/custom fields and custom taxonomies.